# How to represent Enterprise Application's Architecture in a document?

Tags: architecture, uml, n-tier-architecture

Please guide me to represent a complex Java / Java EE based n-tier Enterprise Application's Architecture in a document using a modeling language.

And advise me on what are all the things we need to represent about such applications in a document.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise architecture is not software architecture. In fact, EA is not really all that important to coders which explains why no one else has answered your question here at stackoverflow. Here are the top 3.

- [TOGAF](http://www.opengroup.org/togaf/) is the 800 pound gorilla in this space.
- [ZF](http://www.zachman.com) is considered as an alternative that is more focused on static analysis
- [PEAF](http://www.pragmaticea.com/peaf.htm) is for those who consider the first two as too heavyweight for their tastes.

Maybe you are really just asking about how to document a software architecture. Chances are that [IEEE Standard 1471](http://www.enterprise-architecture.info/Images/Documents/IEEE%201471-2000.pdf) is more your cup of tea (or Java in this case).

Keep in mind that current software development trends are [turning away](http://www.dynamicalsoftware.com/analysis/code-roller) from this kind of formalized approach.